# "The trait bound `Bson: From<u128>` is not satisfied" error when using the doc! macro with u128 attribute

Tags: mongodb, rust

The following function leads to the error mentioned in the title:

```rust
pub async fn read_foo(client: mongodb::Client, key: u128) -> Option<mongodb::bson::Document> {
    client
    .database("db")
    .collection("col")
    .find_one(mongodb::bson::doc! {"key": key}, None)
    .await
    .expect("Could not connect to database")
}
```

This function works with u32, i64 but not u128. I need u128 here, what do I do?

Comment: How are the data stored in database? AFAIK, there's no native way to have 128-bit integers in MongoDB, so that search shouldn't give anything even if it compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function`Bson::From(u128)` was called to convert the value of type `u128` into one of the variants of the enum [Bson](https://docs.rs/bson/2.0.0/bson/enum.Bson.html), which defines all the supported BSON types. However, because there is no valid variant for `u128` the compiler complained and threw the error message.

I can think of two workarounds, but don't know if any of them works for you. One is use `string` instead of `u128` as the value type if you just wanted to store it in MongoDB without calculations, and the other is use Decimal128 if 34 decimal digits of precision is acceptable.

If you go the latter way, please pay attention that it seems the support for Decimal128 has not fully supported yet. See the [doc](https://docs.rs/bson/2.0.0/bson/struct.Decimal128.html).

Comment: Thanks, I eventually decided to use a hex string, don't know why I didn't think of that initially.